# generate images from video url iOS

Tags: ios, avassetimagegenerator

I have this problem that I'm facing from the past 2 days now.I need to generate images from a video.I'm using `AVAssetImageGenerator` and I'm using the method

```
'generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:times completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef  image, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError * _Nullable error)'
```

Now I'm getting images in an array and these images are different as per the print description.But when I set those images on an `UIImage`,I'm missing some images and I'm getting some duplicate images.Here is the code that I've been using which I have done:

```
- (IBAction)editButtonClicked:(id)sender {

AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:self.asset];
imageGenerator.maximumSize = CGSizeMake(200.0f,0.0f);

CMTime duration = self.asset.duration;
NSMutableArray *times = [NSMutableArray array];
CMTimeValue increment = duration.value/20;
NSLog(@"%lld",increment);
CMTimeValue currentValue = 0;
while (currentValue <= duration.value) {
     NSLog(@"%lld",increment);
     NSLog(@"currentValue==%lld",currentValue);
    CMTime time = CMTimeMake(currentValue, duration.timescale);
    CMTimeShow(time);
    [times addObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:time]];
    currentValue+=increment;
    NSLog(@"%lld",increment);
    NSLog(@"currentValue===%lld",currentValue);
}

__block NSUInteger imageCount = times.count;
__block NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray array];

     __block  AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler;
[imageGenerator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:times completionHandler:^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef  image, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
     static NSInteger counter = 0;
    if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
        UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
        [images addObject:image1];
        NSLog(@"%@",images);
        counter++;
        NSLog(@"%ld",(long)counter);
        if(counter == imageCount){
            NSLog(@"inside if");

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // 2
                MyTableViewController *myTableVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyTableViewController"];

             myTableVC.images = [images mutableCopy];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:myTableVC animated:YES];
            });


        }
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Failed to create thumbNail image");
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that I am using in one of my app which is currently in app store available and works absolutely fine. This code takes the first frame of the video and generates the image out of it.

```
AVURLAsset *asset1 = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:toPath] options:nil];
            AVAssetImageGenerator *generate1 = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc] initWithAsset:asset1];
            generate1.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES;
            NSError *err = NULL;
            CMTime time = CMTimeMake(1, 2);
            CGImageRef oneRef = [generate1 copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:&err];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:oneRef];
```

Hope this code was useful to you. Lemme know your comments :) Happy coding buddy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceBefore = kCMTimeZero;
    imageGenerator.requestedTimeToleranceAfter = kCMTimeZero;
```

I added these two lines and now i get the perfect result that I needed.I still am not 100% sure what these properties do but I got what I needed.Now if anyone explains about these properties,it will save me some time as I will be exploring these properties sooner or later.Just copy the code and you will see everything works perfectly fine now. :-)

Comment: As stated in docs, *The actual time of a generated image is within the range [requestedTime-requestedTimeToleranceBefore, requestedTime+requestedTimeToleranceAfter] and may differ from the requested time for efficiency.* When requested frame at specific time, renderer should find the nearest keyframe (which has a full frame image) and apply deltas up to requested timestamp to it. If tolerance is zero, you'll get exact image (at processing speed cost). The more time tolerance is, processing will be faster, but image's timestamp will be inaccurate (depends on number of keyframes in your video).

Comment: Seems like a valid explanation.........thanks a lot dude......for now its clear to me but it will take some time to know what goes behind the scenes........thanks :-)